# java8 Hashmap sort error

Tags: java, hashmap, java-8

I have a map:

```
private Map<String, AtomicInteger> keywordMap = new HashMap<String, AtomicInteger>();
```

I'm trying to sort the `Map` by value (`AtomicInteger`), in Java 8, with the following code:

```
keywordMap
        .entrySet()
        .parallelStream()
        .sorted().forEachOrdered(e -> System.out.print(e.getKey()));
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap$Node cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
```

The error occurs in this line: `.forEachOrdered(e -> System.out.print(e.getKey()));`

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: You have `==` instead of `=`

Comment: Check this, mby can help you. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEachOrdered-java.util.function.Consumer-

Answer (score 7):

Try to use:

```
Stream<Map.Entry<K,V>> keywordMap = keywordMap.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue());
```

Comment: i got compile error in sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue());

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you try to use `sorted()` to sort a stream of `Map.Entry` instances. `Map.Entry` does not implement the `Comparable` interface, and that's why you get the `ClassCastException`. So you will have to supply a suitable comparator yourself.

Also, `AtomicInteger` does not implement `Comparable`, and that is why you cannot use `Map.Entry.comparingByValue()`. You really have to write your own comparator:

```
keywordMap.entrySet()
    .parallelStream()
    .sorted((a,b) -> Integer.compare(a.getValue().get(), b.getValue().get()));
```

However, `AtomicInteger` does not implement `Comparable` for a reason. Typically, `AtomicIntegers` are accessed by multiple threads and thus they can change during the sorting, which might lead to undesirable results (exceptions, even).

Comment: `.sorted(Comparator.comparingInt( e -> e.getValue().get() ))`…

Comment: For future readers...using string instead of int.         .sorted((a,b) -> a.compareTo(b))
or
.sorted((a,b) -> a.compareToIgnoreCase(b))